# MySQL InnoDB 1 field used twice in foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I don't know if this have been asked, because i don't know the best keyword for this.

But here is my problem. Let's say i have 4 tables like these:

```
Type: typeId, ...
TypeFields: typeId, fieldId, ...
Item: itemId, typeId, ...
ItemValues: itemId, typeId, fieldId, ...
```

The base idea is I want to make a dynamic table. The `TypeFields` table defines what the `Item` fields are for its `typeId` value, and `ItemValues` should follow `TypeFields` table for its value.

Now I am confused to set the Foreign Key for `ItemValues`'s `typeId` as it is referenced from `Item` and also referenced together with `fieldId` from `TypeFields`.

Is this design is wrong? If so please show me the right way.

Thanks

Comment: I know you tried to explain really well, but it's still confusing.  An sqlfiddle.com is worth a thousand words - can you put something together and provide a link to it?  Even though you're still working on what exactly it is that you want...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ee28
The problem is on `ItemValues` table. look at constraint `ivfk2` and `ivfk3`